# Restricted mean survival time difference over a time period in R using RSMT2

Tags: r, time, mean, survival

I would like to plot delta of RMST over a time period for two groups. X axis --> Time (year), Y axis --> Delta of RMST(days).

```
a=rmst2(time, status, arm, tau=10)
> print(a) 

Between-group contrast 
                   Est. lower .95 upper .95     p
RMST (arm=1)-(arm=0) -0.137    -0.939     0.665 0.738
RMST (arm=1)/(arm=0)  0.981     0.878     1.096 0.738
RMTL (arm=1)/(arm=0)  1.050     0.787     1.402 0.738
```

I would like to plot the above data (including confidence intervals) for all points of time. Is there a function in R to do that or can I somehow make an array or list of the following result object and plot it to achieve the same?

```
a$unadjusted.result
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to *hack* the `survRM2:::plot.rmst2` function so that confidence intervals are passed on to the `plot` function. In the current version of the **survRM2** package (1.0-4) they are not.

To hack the function, type the following at the R prompt:

```
survRM2:::plot.rmst2
```

Copy the code into a new R script file and add the following to the function call:

```
plot_rmst2 <- function (x, xlab = "", ylab = "", col = "red", col.RMST = "pink", 
          col.RMTL = "orange", density = 80, angle = 85, conf.int=TRUE, ...)
```

On lines 35 and 66, insert the following:

```
if(conf.int) lines(fit, lty=2, col="red")
```

Send the function to the R console so that it is available. Then call the function:

```
plot_rms2t(a)
```

### [image]

**Data:**

```
library(survRM2)
D <- rmst2.sample.data()
time <- D$time
status <- D$status
arm <- D$arm
tau <- NULL
x <- D[,c(4,6,7)]
a <- rmst2(time, status, arm, tau=10)
```